# Блокировать клавишу в linux (Insert)

Tags: linux, клавиатура, fedora

Как можно блокировать клавишу INS в Linux?

Пишу книгу, иногда мешает то, что время от времени, случайно нажимаю клавишу INS, переходя в режим замены и затираю ранее набранный текст. Есть ли способ блокировать эту клавишу (чтобы никогда не переходить в режим замены)?

Comment: Что то подобное https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/#s1-Changing_the_Keyboard_Layout должно сработать, но нужно будет сделать свою конфигурацию

Comment: А лучше освоить слепой набор и проблема уйдет сама собой

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен. Двигаюсь в этом направлении. Но пялится все время в монитор тоже не хочу. А так: то на монитор, то на клаву, то в сторону. А там и глаза не так устают

Comment: смотреть на монитор и клавиатуру поочередно может быть плохо для зрения - обычно они очень по разному освещены.

Comment: Постоянный перенос взгляда - одна из основных причин утомления глаз. Учите слепой набор, берегите глаза.